# Wordpress image attachment settings missing

Tags: php, wordpress, image-uploading

I'm currently setting some custom images sizes for Wordpress image library, so that when an image is uploaded it is resized and saved. I have checked the uploads file and the images are being resized.

When I go to select an image the attachment settings dropdown is missing.

[image: This should have a settings section underneath, so that I can select the correct size.]

This is the code to set my custom image size which is in my functions.php file

```
add_image_size( 'custom-size123', 192, true);
```

Comment: when you click the edit image in attachment .There will be settings to resize the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
when you click the edit image in attachment .There will be settings to resize the image
```

[image: Attachment Page]

[image]